# Molecule with 13 total electrons

Tags: molecules

Is there a stable molecule with total number of electrons equal to 13? Molecule can be either organic or inorganic

Comment: Aluminium metal? atomic number 13...

Comment: Apart from $\ce{Al}$ I am not sure whether they exist. You're pretty much always going to need period 2 atoms for this number of electrons and all the molecules I can dream up have an even number of electrons. Maybe someone more experienced in organic synthesis/plenty of knowledge on molecular bonds can explain why (if) this is the case?!

Comment: Nitric oxide NO is stable radical, but sadly, with 15 electrons.

Answer (score 7):

There are quite some molecules that are *persistent* (= live long enough in solution to allow for a spectroscopical characterization, but cannot be isolated) or even *stable* (= can be isolated, bottled and/or used as a starting material) that have an **odd number *n* of electrons**, however $n \ne 13$.

[image: stable or persistent radicals]

Among these **radicals** are the Gomberg radical (**1**), the Koelsch radical (**2**), and the TEMPO radical (**3**).

Answer (score 3):

A cyanide radical has 13 electrons. This stable radical was one of the first detected molecules in the interstellar medium, 1941 by A. McKellar, doi:10.1086/125159

Stable: persists in vacuum; no imaginary IR frequencies (negative eigenvalues). Reactive: diddles with something else, including another one of itself. Given the name, do your chair parade. The unpaired spin mostly resides on the nitrogen. Chemistry is passion, not compassion