# Why are free radicals so reactive?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reactivity, radicals

Why are free radicals are so reactive? They can break almost any bond, including $\ce{C-H}$ bonds, which are fairly stable. Don’t they have an activation energy or something? Do they not also experience steric effects when colliding with reactants ?

Comment: They do experience steric effects.

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8586/molecule-with-13-total-electrons/8587#8587

Answer (score 4):

Radicals are so reactive because they require so much energy to form. When we speak about radical reactivity, "more reactive" generally means a more exothermic hydrogen atom abstraction step. The more exothermic this step, the more the transition state resembles the reactants ([Hammond's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammond's_postulate)), with a correspondingly lower character of the carbon-centered radical product. This makes the reaction less sensitive to the stability of the carbon-centered radical.

This being said, some radicals do have an activation energy, and some don't. The $E_a$ is essentially zero for all hydrogen atom abstractions by fluorine atom, and the free energy barrier arises solely from the [pre-exponential factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-exponential_factor) of the Arrhenius equation ($k=Ae^{-E_{a}/(RT)}$), which is near 13 for the halogenations listed below.

[image]

The activation energies for abstraction by chlorine atoms are also exceedingly small, but there is a slight preference for more highly substituted $\ce{C-H}$ bonds. Lastly, the activation energies for abstraction by bromine atoms are substantial, clearly showing a preference for abstraction of 3°, 2°, and 1° $\ce{C-H}$ bonds in that order. It is because of these differences in activation energies that we observe the varying regioselectivities of the different halogenation reactions$^{[1]}$.

---

<sub>$[1]$ Anslyn, E. V.; Dougherty, D. A. *Modern Physical Organic Chemistry*; University Science: Sausalito, CA, 2006.</sub>