# Major product of radical fluorination vs bromination

Tags: organic-chemistry, kinetics, radicals

[image]

I understand what structure is formed by using $\ce{Br2}$ to brominate this alkane, and I know that $\ce{F2}$ will be less selective in its abstraction of hydrogen. However, how can I know where $\ce{F2}$ will primarily react with this alkane? I just know that $\ce{F2}$ will react more readily and be less selective.

Comment: "Less selective" is a bit of an understatement. F2 will react **everywhere**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nearly no thermodynamic aspect to this reaction. The activation energy for any alkane hydrogen abstraction by a fluorine radical is essentially 0$^{[1]}$. This means that there is an equally likely chance of fluorinating at any given position. In this case, we need only know the proportions of [homotopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topicity) hydrogen. Homotopic hydrogen are labelled with the same colors in the molecule:

[image: Homotopic]

The proportion in decreasing order is 9:6:1:1:1. That means that we should expect about the following yield of monofluorinated products:

[image]

As an aside, you would never realistically expect to obtain a monofluorinated product. The fluorination of alkanes is violent, extremely fast, and only gets faster upon fluorination.

---

<sub>$^{[1]}$ [Chemistry StackExchange, Why are free radicals so reactive?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/64025/15410)</sub>